# Convert a list to a string list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

Please look at the code:

```
// get column list from entity framework
var listID = from Ines in ineContext.IneDetailRecords
             select Ines.InePIN.ToString().ToList();
string PIN = something;
if(!listID.Contains(PIN))
    // save it to DB
```

InePIN is a cloumn in SQL Server DB, the type is varchar(20).

The exception is:

```
Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Collections.Generic.List<char>>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<string>'
```

Comment: Note that the entire `ToList` is harmful, not helpful.  `IEnumerable` (and also most `IQueryable` query providers) will support `Contains`, so you can just call that directly.  If you're going to be searching *lots* of pins, and not just one, then you should use a data structure that supports searching better, because `List` isn't designed for that.  `HashSet<string>` would be the best choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to apply the ToList method on result of query but not on the selected column i.e `Ines.InePIN.ToString().ToList()`

**Change**

```
var listID = from Ines in ineContext.IneDetailRecords
                                       select Ines.InePIN.ToString().ToList();
```

**To**

```
var listID = (from Ines in ineContext.IneDetailRecords
                                       select Ines.InePIN.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You must convert the whole list ToString()

```
var listID = (from Ines in ineContext.IneDetailRecords
             select Ines.InePIN.ToString()).ToList();
```

And have a look at this link for a better understanding of type covariance http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx